# Table with multiple Dependent Variables

Tags: r, dataframe

How can i create a table with the following data:

Initial Data Table:

[image]

End Table Result:

[image]

Here would be the code easily inputted into R (which I would read from csv file during operation):

```
Date = c(20170101,20170101,20170102,20170102,20170102,20170102,20170103)
Person = c("Adam","Adam","Adam","Ben","Ben","Ben","Ben")
Fruit = c("Apple", "Pear","Bananna","Blueberry","Cherry","Grape","Grape")
z= data.frame(Date,Person,Fruit)
```

Comment: Generally, you should both show the output and describe what the translation rule from input to output is. I'm removing the data.table tag since you should only use it for questions about the package, not just to get attention from folks who follow the tag or request an answer with that package without even having installed it yourself...

Comment: The logic seems okay, but we should warn about 1) having blank spaces created in data frames and 2) stacking multiple items into a single vector position. It's possible, but you will be working against the grain

Comment: Try this for now `reshape2::dcast(z, Person ~ Date, value.var = "Fruit", fun=toString)`

Comment: i understand.  this will be for a formatted report (likely produced by Rmarkdown) and this is how i'd like it presented.  If there is a better/easier way i'm all ears.

Comment: that worked well, however, it's not great formatting wise (b/c fruit are converted to long string (in my real data set)).  If I could get the text to wrap or have one fruit per line that would be ideal.  Is it possible?

Comment: The [tag:pander] package looks like one way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpander%5D+multiline

Answer (score 1):

The `tapply()` function can arrange values into a matrix object using the `c` function. The values get encapsulated in lists:

```
with(z, tapply(Fruit, list(Person,Date), FUN=c))

     20170101    20170102    20170103
Adam Character,2 "Bananna"   NULL    
Ben  NULL        Character,3 "Grape"
```

You can then display that matrix object with pander:

```
library(pander)
panderOptions('keep.line.breaks', TRUE)
mytable <- with(z, tapply(Fruit, list(Person,Date), FUN=c))
pandoc.table(mytable, style="multiline")

----------------------------------------------------------
  &nbsp;    20170101           20170102          20170103 
---------- ----------- ------------------------ ----------
 **Adam**  Apple, Pear         Bananna             NULL   

 **Ben**      NULL     Blueberry, Cherry, Grape   Grape   
----------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want the lines separating the "cells" you can use style="grid". The output then looks like:

```
+----------+-------------+--------------------------+------------+
|  Person  |  20170101   |         20170102         |  20170103  |
+==========+=============+==========================+============+
|   Adam   | Apple, Pear |         Bananna          |            |
+----------+-------------+--------------------------+------------+
|   Ben    |             | Blueberry, Cherry, Grape |   Grape    |
+----------+-------------+--------------------------+------------+
```

If you use paste0 with collapse you can remove the commas and use linefeeds instead:

```
mytable <- with(z, tapply(Fruit, list(Person,Date), FUN=paste0,  collapse="\n"))
```

The structure of the matrix is now different, with each entry being a character value of length-1, but that then does get displayed in a pandoc table with each Fruit on a single line:

```
pandoc.table(mytable, style="multiline")  # or style ="grid" as above
#------------
-------------------------------------------
  &nbsp;    20170101   20170102   20170103 
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 **Adam**    Apple     Bananna       NA    
              Pear                         

 **Ben**       NA     Blueberry    Grape   
                        Cherry             
                        Grape              
-------------------------------------------
```